# Money transfer to Turkey

Tags: united-states, banking, transfer, turkey

My partner from the USA has sent me money (a few million dollars) to Turkey, the transfer is now exactly 14 days ago, have received until now still no money receipt, the money should be on the korrespodentenbank. My question how can I see without Swift code where the money is exactly. And is this all normal with the length ? Can you give me some info thanks

Comment: I need help It’s very important

Comment: Have you actually met your 'partner' in the flesh? How did you come to know them? Did you have to help them send you a few million dollars, like for example by sending them some money first, like a fee? Did they say they would send the millions of dollars to a bank account? Why? For what purpose is the money? Do you have the bank details? Please answer these questions. Seems strange you are doing million-dollar level transactions yet you are asking here.